# How to Use the OR operator

Tags: java

I was working with an if statement:

```
if(test == 1 || test == 2){
    do something
}
```

I am working in Java and somehow this code produces the error of "bad operand type". I know that it is the OR (||) but I don't know how to fix it.
Code:

```
public static int[] map = 
//1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
{ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, //0
  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, //1
  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, //2
  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, //3
  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, //4
  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, //5
  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, //6
  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, //7
  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, //8
  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, //9
};
public static int mapRow, mapCol;
public static int mapRef = (mapRow + (mapCol * 10)) - 1;

String grass = "[ ] ";
String water = "{} ";

private int counter = 0;

void mapCreate(){
    while(counter != 99){
        if((counter = 0) || (counter = 10) || (counter = 20) || (counter = 30) || (counter = 40) || (counter = 50) 
                                           || (counter = 60) || (counter = 70) || (counter = 80) || (counter = 90) || (counter = 100)){
            if(map[counter] == 1){
                System.out.println(grass);
            } else if(map[counter] == 2){
                System.out.println(water);
            }
        } else {
            if(map[counter] == 1){
                System.out.print(grass);
            } else if(map[counter] == 2){
                System.out.print(water);
            }
        }
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Error:

```
mapcreater.java:27: error: bad operand types for binary operator '||'
        if((counter = 0) || (counter = 10) || (counter = 20) || (counter = 30) ||         (counter = 40) || (counter = 50)
```

Comment: that looks fine, how is test defined?

Comment: Thats perfectly valid usage. please show us the error in your IDE.

Comment: test is an integer and how would i show you the error

Comment: What's `test`? It's probably the "somehow".

Comment: How would you show the error? How'd you show us the code? By typing.

Comment: Present a minimal example that includes all relevant code, the complete error message, and point out where the line numbers referenced in the error message are to be found in the code.

Comment: That is *radically* different; all you're doing is assignments, and not to booleans-so `||` doesn't apply.

Comment: but how would i do it? I thought that is the way for or

Comment: See how much easier it is if you just include the actual code in the first place? It simply lets us help you faster.

Comment: Stop doing assignments and do compares instead, like you did in your fake example.

Comment: oh my. Sorry guys i just realized i didn't do == I'm so sorry

Comment: No reason to apologize; just beware that simplifying your code to the point it behaves differently can be misleading, and that providing complete information is usually more efficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't compare `int` values with `=`, the assignment operator.  Use `==` to compare, which results in the needed `boolean`.  Change

```
if((counter = 0) ||
```

to

```
if((counter == 0) || // And the others after it also.
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the type of the `test` variable. You may be attempting to compare a non-numeric type with a literal number.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be

```
if((counter == 0) || (counter == 10) || (counter == 20) || (counter == 30)
```

Notice the double `==`.

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers apply directly, this would be a suitable case for the [`%` (or modulus) operator](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/Intro/expr-mod.html) as it can greatly simply the code:

```
// use `==` (equality), not `=` (assignment)
if (counter % 10 == 0) {  
  // when counter is 0, 10, 20, etc ..
  ..
}
```

Now, the *type error* is "bad operand type" because assignments used as expressions evaluate to the value they were assigned:

Thus, `counter = 0` evaluates to 0 (typed `int`), `counter = 10` evaluates to 10 (typed `int`) which leads to `0 || 10` (typed as `int || int`), and that doesn't make sense in Java - one, or both in this case, of the operands (values) supplied to the operator were invalid because Java only accepts `||` when it is typed as `boolean || boolean`.

Conversely, `counter == 0` evaluates to a boolean and `counter == 10` evaluates to a boolean and thus Java is happy with the type of the expression which is `boolean || boolean`.